# Entity Framework 6 - ORA-00932 while joining with ToString

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm testing out **Entity Framework 6.2** with an oracle database but facing issues while trying to join on multiple conditions with convertion.

I need to match `TABLE2_ID (NUMBER)` with `TABLE2.ID (VARCHAR2)` which are different value types.
The problem is that the `ToString()` method translates into `TO_NCLOB` instead of `TO_NCHAR` which would work.

```
var query = from table1 in context.TABLE1
            join table2 in context.TABLE2 on table1.TABLE2_ID.ToString() equals table2.ID
            select  new
            {
                table1.NAME,
                table2.TEXT
            };
```

The generated SQL looks as following:

```
SELECT 
1 AS "C1", 
"Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
"Extent2"."TEXT" AS "TEXT"
FROM  "USER"."TABLE1" "Extent1"
INNER JOIN "USER"."TABLE2" "Extent2" ON 
  (CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."TABLE2_ID" IS NULL) THEN N'' 

   // At this point I need TO_NCHAR
   ELSE TO_NCLOB("Extent1"."TABLE2_ID") END) = "Extent2"."ID"
```

This results in:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NCLOB

I know there are many questions with almost the same exception but only with different use cases, so please have a look how I can solve this problem.
For e.g. is there a way to override the `ToString()` SQL translation?

**MAIN PROBLEM:** LINQ to SQL `.ToString()` converts into `TO_NCLOB` but I need `TO_NCHAR` or another solution.

I use **Visual Studio 2017** with **Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017 12.2.0.11**

Comment: Can't test, so all I can do is to suggest trying the alternative LINQ left outer join syntax, e.g. instead of `join table2 in ...` try `from result in context.TABLE2.Where(table2 => table1.TABLE2_ID != null && table1.TABLE2_ID.Value.ToString() == table2.ID && table2.MATCH == "VALUE").DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I simplified the case for my problem. I tried your code but it results in the same SQL translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly `.ToString()` isn't implemented that well in Oracle Entity Framework. So I got a workaround by this [SO question accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271718/oracle-entity-framework-call-custom-function-edit-distance).
Installing `EntityFramework.Functions` Nuget Package and using the `TO_NCHAR` built in Oracle function did the trick as following:

```
public static class OracleFunctions
{
    [Function(FunctionType.BuiltInFunction, "TO_NCHAR")]
    public static string ToNChar(this string value) => Function.CallNotSupported<string>();
}
```

Overriding OnModelCreating in DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention(typeof(OracleFunctions)));
}
```

And then I can use it like this which works flawless:

```
var query = from table1 in context.TABLE1
            join table2 in context.TABLE2 on table1.TABLE2_ID.ToNChar() equals table2.ID
            select  new
            {
                table1.NAME,
                table2.TEXT
            };
```